# Poland tourist visa

Tags: schengen-visas, poland

My fiancé’s EEA family permit UK visa got refused as my fiancé is Indian citizen and we have appealed in court as well and we are waiting date from court to attend it but now she is applying to Poland tourist visa for my father’s wedding so she will get refused again or should we not even proceed further..? Please share information if anyone knows best of it